# Массив из разных типов

Tags: массивы, хранилище, c++

Существует ли возможность в c++ сделать массив из разных типов? Или какое-то хранилище-переменную, в которой можно хранить разнотиповые вещи? У меня есть несколько структур, и массив, который будет динамически изменяться, и вот хотелось бы как-то добавлять в него значения разных типов.

Comment: Уже предложили void* (1). Есть объедко-ориентированный способ, построенный на иерархии классов, см. ответ @KoVadim. Но типы д. быть соответствующими -- типы классов-наследников базового. Встроенные типы (по терминологии java, если не ошибаюсь -- "примитивные") не подходят. (2) Ну и третий способ -- union (что идеологически не сильно отличается от первого, или, при наличии поля-селектора -- от второго (см. RTTI). Ну и традиционный вопрос -- а оно Вам точно надо?

Comment: Возможно, то, что Вам требуется, называется Algebraic Data Types, но это уже не C++, а языки высокого уровня. Возможно -- ada, всякие ML'и, включая Ocaml & F#, Scala, Наskell и т.д.

Answer (score 3):

Предложу ещё третий, более с++ способ. Какие разрообразные объекты у Вас не были бы, все равно у них есть общий предок (да, `void*` - это вырожденный случай и обычно говорит либо о сильной преждевременной оптимизации или просто незнания ООП). Итак, первое - нужно написать базовый класс. От него наследуются другие классы для разных данных. Даже если нужно хранить строку и число.

Так как есть базовый класс, то можно написать `std::vector<BaseClassName> vec;` и уже есть массив объектов.

Пусть нужно вывести всех их на печать. Для этого для каждого наследника нужно определить метод вида

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const YourType& dt);
```

И все, можно будет выводить на печать таким кодом

```
for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) std::cout << vec[i] << std::endl;
```

Очень просто.

Но пусть нужно сохранять объекты и загружать с файла. Добавим в базовый тип виртуальный метод "getObjectType", "getObjectSize", "saveToStream" и "loadFromStream". Каждый наследник должен будет их определить. Теперь при сохранении где то так

```
fstream fs;
fs.write(vec.size(), sizeof(size_type));
for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
   int t = vec[i].getObjectType();
   size_t s = vec[i].getObjectSize();
   fs.write(t, sizeof(t));
   fs.write(s, sizeof(s));
   vec[i].writeToStream(fs);
}
```

красиво?

А вот с загрузкой немного сложнее. Нужно будет хранить массив соответствий "тип объекта"->"ссылка на конструктор". Но при небольшом кол-ве объектов, можно и if-else или switch

```
size_type c;
fs.read(c, sizeof(c));
for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
   int t;
   size_t s;
   BaseObj* bb;
   fs.read(t, sizeof(t)); fs.read(s, sizeof(s));
     switch (t) {
     case 1:
       bb = new IntObject();
       break;
     case 2:
       bb = new StringObject();
       break;
     //....
     default:
       // unknown object, can skip
       fs.seekg (s, fs.beg);
       break;
     }
     bb->loadFromStream(fs, s);
}
```

**upd**

Главное не забывать делать методы виртуальными,  а также сделать виртуальным деструктор. Конечно, если классы не будут иметь общего предка, то все это работать не будет.

Comment: @KoVadim А какой предок у типа int?

Comment: никакой. Это базовый тип. Но все сильно зависит от задачи автора. Возможно будет смысл сделать объект IntObject. А может автору просто нужно хорошо подумать.

Comment: @KoVadim но стоит оценить элегантность костыля, который прижился в Java. А ведь лет двадцать и в C++ творилось нечто подобное, вместе с кучей библиотек контейнерных классов.

Comment: Тот костыль, что есть int и Integer?

Comment: @KoVadim Конечно. Там вроде три таких сладких парочки?

Comment: я не знаю, о каких Twix'ах речь.

Comment: @KoVadim попутал. Twix'ов больше:

     Primitive type  Wrapper class
     boolean          Boolean
     byte          Byte
     char          Character
     float          Float
     int          Integer
     long          Long
     short          Short
     double          Double

Comment: Не думаю, что это будет работать с произвольными классами, в которых есть виртуальные методы.

При загрузке такого объекта из файла как минимум надо устанавливать правильный vpointer. А скорее всего вообще надо сначала вызывать конструктор для такого объекта и т.д.

Comment: Что именно не будет работать?

Comment: Указатель на таблицу виртуальных функций после чтения из файла.

Answer (score 1):

да такое можно сделать, но  если вам это понадобилось то скорее всего имеет смысл переделать архитектуру программы.

реализовать это можно например в виде велосипеда над указателями Void.

или гораздо лучший вариант это использовать boost

boost::Any  [вот тут можно почитать](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/any.html)

в любом случае, лучше сначала подумать над архитектурой.

**UPD** 
собственно  пример изменения архитектуры привёл  KoVadim...